# Node.JS and System V Queues / sysv

Tags: javascript, node.js, sysv, sysv-ipc

I've files written in PHP that are using SYSV functions of Linux Systems. The functions that are used in the code being: `msg_send`, `msg_receive` and `msg_get_queue`. My team wants to have the same functionality written in Node.JS. The closest I was at: https://github.com/coderz/node-sysv-ipc. The above solution seems to be half baked. Is there any node module readily available that can be used to interact with SYSV message queues? Please help me out for the same.

Comment: Possible Dublicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546898/system-v-message-queues-for-node-js